# Computing the Edge Chromatic Polynomial of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there a recursive formulae to compute the edge chromatic polynomial of a graph?
The following formulae is known for the vertex chromatic polynomial of a grapg $G$
   $P(G,x)=P(G-uv, x)- P(G/uv,x)$ (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial)

Note that by the formulae I do not mean using the above formuale for the line graph of the graph.

Actually I would like to compute the edge chromatic polynomial of all graphs with seven vertices and I could not compute some of them by MAPLE.

Comment: It really feels like any reasonable recursion will be more or less isomorphic to doing the classical formula on the line graph.